# jQuery external link anchor animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could not find a correct answer.
I'd like to open the page then animate scrolled to the `ID` I called.

here is my code.

**JQuery**

```
   $(window).bind("load", function () {
              var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
                $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('a[href="#' + urlHash + '"]').offset().top}, 1000);
    });
```

**Html**

```
<div class="space"></div>
<div id="anchor">This is anchor</div>
```

**css**

```
.space{height:800px;}
#anchor{font-size:25px;height:800px;}
```

then jQuery is not working, so I pasted the following code to console

```
 $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('a[href="#' + anchor+ '"]').offset().top}, 1000);
```

The error says

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

http://jsfiddle.net/4mjmw/1/

How could I solve this error? thanks

Comment: Where is the anchor in your markup? http://jsfiddle.net/2A9bJ/

Comment: Your Fiddle has two major problems: there is no anchor with a href, and there is no window.location.hash

Comment: I tested on local, I just inserted http://localserver/page#anchor.

Comment: the `anchor` i used `id="anchor"` should i use `name='anchor'` instead or a href? thanks

Comment: @undefined, yes I found my mistakes! i used href in JS but I dont have any anchor in html....Thanks a lot.

Comment: @David yes you are right! the mistake is silly, Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works: http://jsfiddle.net/4mjmw/4/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4mjmw/4/show/#abc

I added an href to the anchor and moved the script to HTML.

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
          var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('a[href="#' + urlHash + '"]').offset().top}, 1000);
      });
```